Solve equation $(kX+Q)(Q+2kR)^{-1}(kX+Q)=Q$ where $X,Q,R$ are positive semidefinite matrices and $k$ is a scalar
Solve equation $(kX+Q)(Q+2kR)^{-1}(kX+Q)=Q$ where $X,Q,R$ are positive semidefinite matrices and $k$ is a positive scalar real number. $X$ is the unknown variable here. $Q,R,k$ are known.
As a trivial educated guess just to see what the solution might look like, if we assume $X,Q,R$ are scalar, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{(kX+Q)^2}{(2kR+Q)} &= Q \\
(kX+Q)^2 &= 2kRQ+Q^2 \\
X&=\frac{\sqrt{2kRQ+Q^2} - Q}{k}
\end{align}
Obviously this assumes the multiplication commutes. What can we do about the matrix case? I welcome some pointers, or even some simplifications, such as assuming they are diagonal ...

How did you come up with such an equation? Perhaps it might give some intuition
